What key or combination is <71> in pynput library
I had a <71> in pynput keyboard .txt file made but I do not know what pressed.  I know that by pressing some keys like the numpad it takes numbers between <> but <71> is unknown for me.
Can anyone tell me what combination or key is it?

The exact numeric values of the key codes are platform-specific.  They should all be listed in the pynput.keyboard.Key Enum - pynput.keyboard.Key.__members__ will show you the complete list.

Post a [mre] with debugging details.

I resolved it is ALT + G, thank you guys.
